# RewriteRule not doing anything

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I do have one problem with htaccess rewriting. I tried to change my URL from
`lug/de/projekt?p=4`
to
`lug/de/projekt/4`

with this Rule:

```
RewriteRule ^projekt/([0-9]+)/?$ projekt?p=$1 [NC,L]
```

But it's not working. Are my other Rules (removing file extension) a problem? Or could anyone point me in the right direction?

EDIT: As asked here's the whole htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^projekt/([0-9]+)/?$ projekt.php?p=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^projekt/([0-9]+)/?$ projekt?p=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]
```

Comment: Can you post the whole file? Or at least the lines that precede this one?

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Are you getting 404?

Comment: Yes, I am getting a 404. Here's my .htaccess:
`RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^projekt/([0-9]+)/?$ projekt.php?p=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^projekt/([0-9]+)/?$ projekt?p=$1 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]`

Comment: Where did you save this file? `^projekt/` means that "projekt" must be relative to the current directory in which the htaccess file it put.

Comment: I've got the subfolders "/de/projekt/" with the .php file "projekt.php" and the htaccess is in the root. Do I have to move the htaccess to the "projekt" folder?

Comment: @user3252019 By using `^projekt/` you're saying that the URL from the current path **has** to start with "projekt/". You can change it in the root to `^(de|en)/projekt/` to support de/en/other languages.

Comment: Thx, that solved it. After I put the htaccess in the correct folder it works like charm!